# Oracle Update First 20 Records Based on an Order By

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table that I am trying to update a column off. The thing is there are 40 records in which I order by an impact. I then want to take the top 10 of those (based on their impact) and update them

```
UPDATE mytable
SET status = 'red'
WHERE status IN
(

    SELECT status
      FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM mytable
        WHERE status = 'green'
        ORDER BY impact DESC
        )
)
AND ROWNUM <= 10
```

I tried putting the ROWNUM inside the WHERE IN statement but it will just ignore it and update all 40 records. When I do it how I have it above then it picks 10 but it doesn't pick the top 10 it just picks them randomly. I am guessing it's ignoring the ORDER BY impact.

I've tried searching for a similar issue but cant find anything.
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You need to create some fake  data similar to yours, some example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it was me I would use the dense_rank
you might have an edge case where the impact for more than one row is the same so you might get more than 40 rows

not sure status is the actual column you want, like the other answer you might want the PK to drive the update

```
UPDATE mytable
SET status = 'red'
WHERE status IN
(

    SELECT status
      FROM (
        SELECT status, dense_rank() over (order by impact desc) color_rank
        FROM mytable
        WHERE status = 'green'
        )
      where color_rank <= 40
)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's updating any record with those statuses where you want specific records. In your where clause, try using an id column instead of status so

```
WHERE id in (select id from mytable where status='green' and rownum<=10 order by impact desc )
```

Comment: Thank you, using an ID in the WHERE IN fixed it

Answer (score 1):

This may be work out:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET status = 'red'
WHERE status IN
(

    SELECT level_0_impact
      FROM (
        SELECT impact level_0_impact
        FROM mytable
        WHERE status = 'green'
        ORDER BY impact DESC
        )
    where rownum <=10
);
```

I've just tested with hr.employees and it work:

```
update hr.employees
set salary=99999
where salary in 
(select level0
   from (
          select salary level0
          from hr.employees
          order by salary desc)
   where rownum < 4 
);
```